# Accidentaly deleted initrd and vmlinuz

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, debian

Yesterday I suddenly deleted initrd and vmlinuz files in boot folder. Now I can't get in my Debian system, because GRUB can't find vmlinuz and initrd.

I tried to generate new initrd image but I can't chroot system in any Live CD that I'm trying to use. Can someone tell me the exact way to solve this problem?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the filesystem from the LiveCD?

You might need to mount the filesystem first, the LiveCD may not automatically mount it.

From a command line you can use `demsg` to find out the device name of the hard drive, e.g. `/dev/sda1`

Then simply make a mount point and mount it:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/system
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/system
```

From there you should be able to `chroot` into the system

If you know what version of the kernel you had installed (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg` might help) then you could try downloading the `.deb` and unpacking it to get the files you need, e.g.:

```
cd /tmp
dpkg -x linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic_3.16.0-25.33_amd64.deb /tmp
```

You can grab the kernel `.deb` from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/kernel/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I found another solution - I simply installed Debian in VMware and copied these 2 files to my installation of Debian.